# Default list in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I want to store data at run time, I can have a linked list and add at runtime, however as I am new to IOS and objective C, do we have any default list in which we can add our datas, (Datas are two stings and an integer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocoa provides [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray) and [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), a pair of ordered containers similar to Java's `ArrayList` and C#'s `List`. You can add values to `NSMutableArray`, and it will grow as you add more elements; `NSArray` is read-only.

Comment: So I have to create modal kind of class and add that object into NSMutableArray right?

Comment: You need to create a class, inherit `NSObject`, add whatever properties it may need (e.g. two strings and an integer), and then add instances of this class to your `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .plist files to store your data. 
Read more ['Loading data from .plist files'](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/14/loading-data-from-plist-files/), ['How to use plist in iphone?'](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-plist-in-iphone/) or google it like 'load data from .plist'. However you can create `NSArray` or something like this at run time. If you want dive deeper you must read [ObjC Collections Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) or [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) depending on your needs.

NSArray:

```
NSArray *myArray;
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSValue *aValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSString *aString = @"a string";
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDate, aValue, aString, nil];
```

NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSValue *aValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
NSString *aString = @"a string";
[myArray addObject:aDate];
[myArray addObject:aValue];
[myArray addObject:aString];
```

NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary * myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:aDate, aValue, aString forKeys:firstDate, firstValue, firstString];
```

NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSString *aString = @"a string";
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
NSValue *aValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myDict setObject:aString forKey:firstString];
[myDict setObject:aDate forKey:firstDate];
[myDict setObject:aValue forKey:firstValue];
```

Comment: Why the extra retain in `[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] retain];` the alloc is already retaining. This could lead to a leak in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class for your data with default properties and make sure it inherits NSObject then use NSMUtableArray to add/remove elements to the list.

```
// in the .h file of your object
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
    NSString* strAttribute1;
    // add more attributes as you want
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* strAttribute1;

@end

// then in the .m file
// do not forget the #import ""
@implement MyObject
@synthesize strAttribute1;

// override the dealloc to release the retained objects
@end
```

then in your code where you want to make a list of this object

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// add elements and iterate through them

// do not forgot to free the memory if you are not using ARC
[myArray release];
```